# Is there a better way to approach this?

Tags: c++

I'm basically trying to make a program that turns roman numerals into decimal and this is to verify that only roman numerals are being accepted as input.

I'm sure there is more efficient way of doing this. I'm very new to programming.

```
int main() 
{
    string valid = {"IIIIIVIIXIILIICIIDIIMIVIIVVIVXIVLIVCIVDIVMIXIIXVIXXIXLIXCIXDIXMILIILVILXILLILCILDILMICIICVICXICLICCICDICMIDIIDVIDXIDLIDCIDDIDMIMIIMVIMXIMLIMCIMDIMMVIIVIVVIXVILVICVIDVIMVVIVVVVVXVVLVVCVVDVVMVXIVXVVXXVXLVXCVXDVXMVLIVLVVLXVLLVLCVLDVLMVCIVCVVCXVCLVCCVCDVCMVDIVDVVDXVDLVDCVDDVDMVMIVMVVMXVMLVMCVMDVMMXIIXIVXIXXILXICXIDXIMXVIXVVXVXXVLXVCXVDXVMXXIXXVXXXXXLXXCXXDXXMXLIXLVXLXXLLXLCXLDXLMXCIXCVXCXXCLXCCXCDXCMXDIXDVXDXXDLXDCXDDXDMXMIXMVXMXXMLXMCXMDXMMLIILIVLIXLILLICLIDLIMLVILVVLVXLVLLVCLVDLVMLXILXVLXXLXLLXCLXDLXMLLILLVLLXLLLLLCLLDLLMLCILCVLCXLCLLCCLCDLCMLDILDVLDXLDLLDCLDDLDMLMILMVLMXLMLLMCLMDLMMCIICIVCIXCILCICCIDCIMCVICVVCVXCVLCVCCVDCVMCXICXVCXXCXLCXCCXDCXMCLICLVCLXCLLCLCCLDCLMCCICCVCCXCCLCCCCCDCCMCDICDVCDXCDLCDCCDDCDMCMICMVCMXCMLCMCCMDCMMDIIDIVDIXDILDICDIDDIMDVIDVVDVXDVLDVCDVDDVMDXIDXVDXXDXLDXCDXDDXMDLIDLVDLXDLLDLCDLDDLMDCIDCVDCXDCLDCCDCDDCMDDIDDVDDXDDLDDCDDDDDMDMIDMVDMXDMLDMCDMDDMMMIIMIVMIXMILMICMIDMIMMVIMVVMVXMVLMVCMVDMVMMXIMXVMXXMXLMXCMXDMXMMLIMLVMLXMLLMLCMLDMLMMCIMCVMCXMCLMCCMCDMCMMDIMDVMDXMDLMDCMDDMDMMMIMMVMMXMMLMMCMMDMMM"};

    string s;
    while (true) {
        cout << "Please enter a roman numeral or Q to quit the program: ";
        cin >> s;

        if (valid.find(s) != string::npos) {
            int num;
            num = intConversion(s);
            cout << num << "\n";
        }
        else if (s == "Q") {
            cout << "Thank you for using the program." << "\n";
            break;
        } else {
            cout << "Invalid letter!" << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: This really belongs over on the following page: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: BTW, your algorithm will fail for the test case: IIIII, which is not a valid Roman number.  Also, VIII is a valid numeral that will fail your test.

Answer (score 1):

That `valid` string is horrendously ugly and unnecessary overhead. I would suggest getting rid of it completely and just let `intConversion()` return an error if the input cannot be converted.

```
bool intConversion(const string &s, int *num)
{
    // parse s and set *num as needed...
    return true or false accordingly;
}

int main()
{
    string s;
    while (true) {
        cout << "Please enter a roman numeral or Q to quit the program: ";
        cin >> s;
        if (s == "Q") {
            cout << "Thank you for using the program." << "\n";
            break;
        }

        int num;
        if (intConversion(s, &num))
            cout << num << "\n";
        } else {
            cout << "Invalid input!" << "\n";
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution.

```
int main() 
{
string valid = {"IVXLCDM"};

string s;
while (true) {
    cout << "Please enter a roman numeral or Q to quit the program: ";
    cin >> s;

    if (valid.find_last_of(s) != string::npos) {
        int num;
        num = intConversion(s);
        cout << num << "\n";
    }
    else if (s == "Q") {
        cout << "Thank you for using the program." << "\n";
        break;
    } else {
        cout << "Invalid letter!" << "\n";
    }
}
return 0;
system("pause");
```

}